# Flutter Web/PWA - call api when user closes tab or PWA installed app

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to call an api when a user closes the tab that's running the application or closes the installed PWA app.

This is not working:

```
  late String token;

  setUserToken() async {
    token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken(true);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    // signOut();
    html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async {
      // do something
      print(token);
      print("closing");

      http.delete(
          Uri.parse(
            '${Helpers().apiUrl()}/location',
          ),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          });
    });
    setUserToken();
  }
```

Also tried `await http.delete`

Edit ***

I just tried calling the api while it was running in cloud functions locally and it worked.

I just noticed this in the logs:

2022-11-06T16:57:48.838Z OPTIONS /location
Function execution took 1936 ms. Finished with status code: 204

Comment: Maybe try not using async for the onBeforeUnload event listener. Is `print("closing");` working?

Comment: yes ... `print("closing")` works. I don't see the difference, but I've been trying from localhost. I'll try deploying it and see what happens.

Comment: deploying didn't help, and neither did taking out async